# Como conseguir un último carácter del array en C

Tags: c

Mientras que el ultimo carácter en Python es `a[-1]`, ¿cuál sería su equivalente en C? ¿O como se conseguiría?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

También podrías utilizar la técnica de `sizeof`.

Se me ocurre un escenario donde por algún motivo extraño no tengas como saber el tamaño del array, ya sea porque hay demasiados módulos en el código espagueti, o porque es larguísimo el código, o porque te dejaron trabajar de a rápido en una parte de un código que asume que tiene un array. O también que sea una cadena de texto:

```
int array_size = sizeof(unknown_size_array)/sizeof(unknown_size_array[0]);
int last_element = unknown_size_array[array_size-1];
```

Un ejemplo un poco rebuscado, pero sólo para poner a prueba esto:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define unknown_size 9

void fill_array_incrementally(int* array_to_fill, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        array_to_fill[i] = (i+1)*100;
}

void print_array(int* array_to_print, int size) {
    printf("Array content: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%i,", array_to_print[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    /*Supon que no conocemos de aqui(...)*/
    int unknown_size_array[unknown_size];

    fill_array_incrementally(unknown_size_array, unknown_size);
    print_array(unknown_size_array, unknown_size);
    /*(...) hasta aca*/
    
    int array_size = sizeof(unknown_size_array)/sizeof(unknown_size_array[0]);
    int last_element = unknown_size_array[array_size-1];

    printf("last: %i\n", last_element);
    return 0;
}
```

Regresando esto:

```bash
$ gcc last.c -o last && ./last
Array content: 100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,
last: 900
```

También funcionaría esta estrategia con tipos `char[]`, como `char palabra[] = "hola"`, pero el último caracter que nos importa no sería el último, sino el penúltimo (osea, en lugar de restar uno, restamos dos, -2 al tamaño), ya que el último siempre es el caracter nulo.

Answer (score 3):

Un array viene definido por un tipo y un tamaño (número de elementos):

```
#define SIZE 1000
   int array[SIZE];
// ~~~       ~~~~
// tipo      tamaño
```

Dado que los índices empiezan en 0, el último elemento será SIZE-1:

```
int ultimo = array[SIZE - 1];
```

En C no puedes hacer como en Python. Python es un lenguaje mucho más moderno que se ha desarrolado en un entorno mucho más benigno que C.

Cuando nació C, los equipos de la época luchaban por tener unos pocos KB de memoria RAM y discos cuya capacidad se medía facilmente en MB. En ese momento cualquier operación innecesaria consumía unos preciosos ciclos de reloj.

Debido a estas serias limitaciones, el lenguaje se diseñó partiendo de la base de que el lenguaje no iba a dar más ayudas de las imprescindibles.

Así, mientras que en Python hay una secuencia que comprueba si la posición es negativa y, en caso contrario, empieza a recorrer el array desde el final, en C el número que pongas entre corchetes se interpreta directamente como un desplazamiento en memoria.

Lo dicho, son lenguajes planteados en momentos muy diferentes de la historia

Comment: De hecho, en Python puedes hacer algo similar. `arreglo[len(arreglo) - 1]`. Solo que por simplicidad se usa `arreglo[-1]`.

Comment: @Mateo entiendo, disculpa mi comentario :)